Is this the most active Ethereum Q&A forum online?
This might be bad community practice, but I wanted to practice asking a question on this forum.
I went with "Is this the most active Ethereum Q&A forum online?".
Thanks.
GS-Ren

There are plenty of communities online, on different social networks, like reddit, discord, x, linkedin, forums, etc.
